# RadioButton is not Checked when Checked property is set to true

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

When the checked property is true , the radio button is not checked in UWP. The radio buttons is not in the group. See the code below.

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RadioButton Content="1" IsChecked="True"/>
        <RadioButton IsChecked="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

You can see only the second radio button is checked.Why?

Comment: Create separate groups for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you grouped them by putting them into the same container.
From UWP [Radio Button documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/radio-button):

Radio buttons work in groups. There are 2 ways you can group radio button controls:

- Put them inside the same parent container.
- Set the GroupName property on each radio button to the same value.

Comment: If I give same name for the group name property for both the radio buttons and isChecked= true , then both the radio buttons is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Purpose of RadioButton is that only single item will be selected at one time when RadioButtons are group together.
If you want multiple selection at a time you can use CheckBox instead on RadioButton.